# How to Taper the Thickness of Solidify Modifier

Tags: modeling, modifiers

How do I taper the thickness of the solidify modifier? As an example, the bottom of a glass bottle is thicker than the rest of the bottle. Is there a way to control/drive the thickening of Solidify so that it tapers procedurally? (I would like to avoid applying and manually editing).

Pictured below is the actual file I'm working on (it's a leg socket for amputees). I would like for the cross section / cutaway to be thicker on the bottom where it meets the seal ring.

[image: Actual file I'm working on]

Comment: You can use vertex group weight to affect thickness on a per vertex basis

Comment: Thank you, this certainly seems to work. However, this method seems reliant upon the number of actual vertices, not the number generated by the subd modifier. Is there a way I can increase the fidelity of the weight map without adding more geometry?

Comment: You can use another object's geometry with a vertex weight proximity modifier or a data transfer modifier set to transfer vertex groups with a duplicate low-poly bottle geometry

Comment: I am unaware of any technique, but if you don't need any specific progression curve few points should suffice. Just set desired weights, then let Blender interpolate linearly between them.

Comment: Thank you both for your comments. It turned out that I needed to create a more complicated thickening on the bottom than a simple solidify with tapering could achieve, so I ended up applying my modifiers and doing it manually. I still learned a lot though, so thank you for pointing me in the right direction. Cheers!